# 401 authorization in python 3

Tags: python, python3

I need a little help with python3 code.
I wrote a code for python2, but after a little modifications in python3,
I can't get this code working again.

Can you provide me any ideas, what and how can be done, to get this code working again?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# python3 version http client
# 

import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import time

param1 = 'value1'
param2 = 'value2'

tm = 60

while True:
    url = "http://a.w.com/?link=11&u=10"
    values = {'param1':value1, 'param2':value2}

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    binary_data = data.encode('ascii')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, binary_data)
    urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    # find only cmd output:
    result = re.search('Wireless(.*)</div>', data)
    print (result.group(1))
```

Code seems to be ok, but I need to add here basic auth login functionality.
I know that in Python 3 auth was changed to oauth, but I don't know how
should I prepare this code to working.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: This question somehow lacks a relation to Ubuntu.

Comment: If the OP is using Ubuntu and chooses to post his question here it is totally on topic for the site. No further explanations needed.

Comment: This isn't the code you are using, it contains multiple errors (just from sight alone). Provide a minimal working example and errormessages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but if any idea is welcome I'd suggest using requests instead of urllib.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

If you need authentication ideas, they are here for you.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication.html

Comment: +1 for python-requests over urllib. Way more intuitive to accomplish this.